# Problema Query server has gone away

Tags: mysql, query

Ocorreu-me um erro na parte da Query

```
mysql_query(): MySQL server has gone away
```

Que tipo de erro é este?

Query:

```
$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO tb_trabalhador  VALUES(0,'".$Nome."','".$Morada."','".$Tipo."','".$Email."','".$AlvaraNumero."','".$AlvaraValidade."','".$AlvaraAnexo."', '".$AcidenteNumero."', 
'".$AcidenteValidade."','".$AcidenteAnexo."','".$SeguroNumero."','".$SeguroValidade."','".$SeguroAnexo."','".$FinancasValidade."','".$FinancasAnexo."','".$SocialValidade."',
'".$SocialAnexo."','".$RemuneracaoValidade."','".$RemuneracaoAnexo."','".$InstaladorNumero."','".$InstaladorValidade."','".$InstaladorAnexo."','".$MontadorNumero."','".$MontadorValidade."','".$MontadorAnexo."')";
```

Estrutura

```
'tb_trabalhador', 'CREATE TABLE `tb_trabalhador` (\n  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,\n  `Nome` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `Morada` text,\n  `Tipo` varchar(45)
 DEFAULT NULL,\n  `Email` text,\n  `AlvaraNumero` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `AlvaraValidade` date DEFAULT NULL,\n  `AlvaraAnexo` longblob,\n  `AcidenteNumero` int(11)
 DEFAULT NULL,\n  `AcidenteValidade` date DEFAULT NULL,\n  `AcidenteAnexo` longblob,
\n  `SeguroNumero` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `SeguroValidade` date DEFAULT NULL,\n  `SeguroAnexo` longblob,\n  `FinancasValidade` date DEFAULT NULL,\n  `FinancasAnexo` longblob,\n  `SocialValidade` date DEFAULT NULL,\n  `SocialAnexo` longblob,\n  `RemuneracaoValidade` date DEFAULT NULL,\n  `RemuneracaoAnexo` longblob,\n  `InstaladorNumero` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `InstaladorValidade` date DEFAULT NULL,\n  `InstaladorAnexo` longblob,\n  `MontadorNumero` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `MontadorValidade` date DEFAULT NULL,\n  `MontadorAnexo` longblob,\n  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)\n) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54293/discussion-on-question-by-chrisadler-problema-query-server-has-gone-away)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regra geral o erro que estás a ver é devido a três problemas:

> mysql_query(): MySQL server has gone away

## Operações realizadas no PHP

Se entre o tempo em que abres a ligação à base-de-dados e a altura em que efectivamente vais interagir com a mesma estás a realizar operações que demoram até estarem concluídas, a ligação à base-de-dados pode ser perdida.

A recomendação aqui é que faças as operações que tens a fazer e abras ligação à base-de-dados quando efectivamente precisas dela.

Em alternativa, podes verificar se a mesma está activa antes de a tentares usar fazendo uso do [mysql_ping()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-ping.php) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> onde podemos ler:

> Ping a server connection or reconnect if there is no connection

Que traduzido:

> Realiza um ping à ligação ao servidor ou restabelece a mesma se não for encontrada.

Para usar dado que o `mysql_ping()` não restabelece a ligação automaticamente:

```php
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'utilizador', 'password');
mysql_select_db('db',$conn);

// blá blá blá 

// antes de correres a consulta de inserção
if (!mysql_ping($conn)) {

  // fecha ligação anterior (mesmo que já não exista, tem que ser fechada)
  mysql_close($conn);

  // volta a ligar
  $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'utilizador', 'password');

  // escolhe base de dados
  mysql_select_db('db',$conn);
}

// a tua consulta para inserir aqui...
```

## Inserção de dados (blob's e afins)

Ao procederes à consultas de inserção, particularmente as que contém BLOB's, estás sujeito a ultrapassar os limites máximos impostos ao pacote que é enviado para o MySQL.

Os limites são definidos em [max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> onde podemos ler na documentação:

> You must increase this value if you are using large BLOB columns or long strings.

Que traduzido:

> Deve aumentar este valor se estiver a utilizar grandes colunas BLOB ou strings longas.

O referido valor pode ser alterados de duas maneiras:

1. Executar uma consulta para alterar o limite até que o servidor seja reiniciado:

   ```
   SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=1073741824;
   ```
2. Alterar o ficheiro de configurações para manter a alteração para sempre:

   No ficheiro `my.ini`, incluir uma linha após `[mysqld]` com:

   ```
   max_allowed_packet=500M
   ```

## Recolha de dados

Se for o caso de aparecer este erro quando estamos a realizar consultas à base-de-dados para recolher dados, o problema poderá estar na quantidade de informação e/ou no tempo que a mesma demora até chegar.

Para estes cenários, é preciso aumentar o tempo da ligação no PHP de forma a garantirmos que as operações correm como esperado.

No início do nosso ficheiro PHP, podemos definir dois valores superiores ao normal de 60 segundos:

```
ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 300);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 300);
```

Comment: Continuo com o mesmo problema.:
Mysql_query(): MySql server has gone away.
Mysql_query():Error Reading Set's header.

e é ao inserir os dados na BD

Comment: Mas tem haver com o tamanho. porque se preencher menos campos funciona.

Comment: @user3253195 Sim, é o tamanho do pacote enviado para a base de dados, tinhamos concluído isso ontem, mas alteraste o `max_allowed_packet` para valores elevados?

Comment: Sim alterei. coloquei 500M

Comment: @user3253195 Alteraste então a partir do ficheiro de configuração, é isso?

Comment: @user3253195 Se a alteração foi a partir do ficheiro de configuração, deverás reiniciar os serviços para que a alteração tenha efeito.